# HTML5 browser local vs internet differences handling MKV and M4A media files

Tags: html, apache, media-player, m4a, mkv

re: http://www.gooplusplus.com/minmedia/demo/minmedia.php

I am working on what may eventually become a **Minimalist Media Server** for Local Area Networks, with option to launch files to Chromecast. It was prompted by a discovery that there are no UPnP/DLNA client Chrome apps or easy media access methods for Chromebooks.

While Plex works on Chromebooks, Chromecast redirection only works through a Plex web link. In any case, most media servers seem like a lot of unnecessary overhead and periodic disk thrashing when all that is wanted is a simple and direct way to play via wifi from a few terabytes of LAN-hosted media files. IMO, thumbnails and category features, etc. just get in the way of the actual viewing or listening.

Enough soapbox, now to the MKV and M4A file anomaly: when I click on a link to an MKV demo video file from my web host (Hostgator), the browser (both Chrome and Firefox) starts downloading instead of playing the MKV file. When I click the link to the same file locally (Civet Web Server, an open-source fork of Mongoose), the MKV file plays normally in an HTML5 browser window.

The opposite occurs with M4A music files. A click on a Hostgator-hosted M4A file link plays in the browser's HTML5 web player. A click on the file hosted locally prompts downloading instead of playing.

So, can some expert out there tell me why links to these two types of media files behave differently locally vs on the internet? Is it a function of the (1) host [Hostgator] or (2) the web server (Apache vs Civet Web)? Is there some mime type, etc. configuration file for Apache or elsewhere that might force how MKV files are handled by my host?

[image: MinMedia Local Area Network (Win7) MKV links]

Comment: Another curious finding is that by simply renaming an MKV file to MP4, it will play in the browser's default HTML5 player from both a local and internet link.

Example: just copy **video.MKV** to **video.mkv.MP4**

An internet click on the first will be downloaded while the second will start playing. A similar quirk happens if you rename **audio.AAC** to **audio.aac.M4A** or **audio.aac.MP4**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: http://www.homenetvideo.com/demo/index.php?/Test%20Formats

How an HTML5 browser like Google **Chrome** handles **MKV, M4V, MOV, M4A, M4B** seems to be dependent on the **web server's config** file.

Here's what I added to my Hostgator **homenetvideo.com .htaccess** file:

```
RemoveType .webm
RemoveType .mpeg
AddType video/webm .webm .mov .m4v .mkv
AddType audio/mpeg .m4b
```

Here's what I added to my LAN web server **civetweb.conf** file:

```
extra_mime_types .m4v=video/mp4,.mov=video/webm,.m4a=audio/mpeg,.m4b=audio/mpeg
```

These formats on both **local network and external** servers now play from the browser **HTML5 player**:

```
VIDEO: MP4 WEBM OGV + .mkv .mov .m4v
AUDIO: MP3 OGG WAV + .m4a .m4b
```

...

[image: Homenet Local Media Server - Test Format]

[image: Homenet - MKV file playing in browser HTML5 player]

Comment: These Apache .htaccess **AddType** entries for MKV, MOV, and M4B work in Google Chrome but **not in Firefox**. (Frankly, I don't even bother with Internet Explorer.)

Comment: For Google Chrome users with VLC installed:

---

     **AddType application/x-vlc-plugin .pls .flv**